# CUDA JuliaSet Whitepaper Example with Vers. 12.3

Tags: cudalink, cuda

As a newbie to using Mathematica with CUDA, I have attempted to execute an example presented in the  "WOLFRAM WHITE PAPER CUDA Programming with the Wolfram Language": @ https://www.wolfram.com/products/CUDAProgrammingWithTheWolframLanguage.pdf

The code below is taken form the example of using CUDALink is as follows (cut and pasted from the pdf):

```
code = "
__global__ void julia_kernel(Real_t * set,
int width, int height, Real_t cx, Real_t cy) {
int xIndex = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
int yIndex = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*blockDim.y;
int ii;
Real_t x = ZOOM_LEVEL*(width/2 - xIndex);
Real_t y = ZOOM_LEVEL*(height/2 - yIndex);
Real_t tmp;
Real_t c;
if (xIndex < width && yIndex < height) {
  for (ii = 0; ii <
MAX_ITERATIONS && x*x + y*y < BAILOUT; ii++) {
tmp = x*x - y*y + cx;
y = 2*x*y + cy;
x = tmp;
}
c = logf(static_cast<Real_t>(0.1) + sqrtf(x*x + y*y));
set[xIndex + yIndex*width] = c;
}
}
 ";

{width, height} = {512, 512};

jset = CUDAMemoryAllocate[Real, {height, width}]


JuliaCalculate = 
    CUDAFunctionLoad[code, 
   "julia_kernel", {{_Real}, _Integer, _Integer, _Real, _Real}, {16, 
    16}, "Defines" -> {"MAX_ITERATIONS" -> 10, 
    "ZOOM_LEVEL" -> "0.0050", "BAILOUT" -> "4.0"}]

 Manipulate[
 JuliaCalculate[jset, width, height, c[[1]], c[[2]], {width, height}];
 ReliefPlot[Reverse@CUDAMemoryGet[jset], 
 ColorFunction \[RightArrow] "Rainbow", 
 DataRange \[RightArrow] {{-2.0, 2.0}, {-2.0, 2.0}}, 
 ImageSize \[RightArrow] 512, Frame \[RightArrow] None, 
 Epilog \[RightArrow] {Opacity[.5], Dashed, Thick, 
 Line[{{{c[[1]], -2}, {c[[1]], 2}}, {{-2, c[[2]]}, {2, 
    c[[2]]}}}]}], {{c, {0, 1}}, {-2, -2}, {2, 2}, Locator, 
    Appearance \[RightArrow] 
    Graphics[{Thick, Dashed, Opacity[.75], Circle[]}, 
    ImageSize \[RightArrow] 50]}]
```

However, when executed after a Needs["CUDALink`"] command and a CUDAQ[] command that returns True, rather than generating the Julia-set graphic in the example it simply returns ReliefPlot[] containing a zero matrix with 0.0 for each entry, with an error indicating that "options are expected rather
than Epilog ...".  It is notable that the variable c defined in
the CUDA code and referred to in the Manipulate command is not initialized. From my meager background with the code block section it would seem that the c variable is not being initialized, even though it defined in the "code" block section.

Has anyone attempted to run this example using Ver. 12.3 and obtained success in generating the manipulable graphic given in the example?

Although I have had success with other CUDA examples in the white paper (ie examples for CUDAFourier[data], CUDADot and the func = Sin[x] + x^2 -1/(1+x), this example has me wondering if I have fully set up CUDALink correctly.

Comment: Manipulate[
  JuliaCalculate[jset, width, height, c[[1]], 
    c[[2]], {width, height}];
  ReliefPlot[CUDAMemoryGet[jset], 
    DataRange -> {{-2.0, 2.0}, {-2.0, 2.0}}, ImageSize -> 512, 
    ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"],
  {{c, {0, 1}}, {-2, -2}, {2, 2}, Locator}]

Comment: You may try this to get the plot.

Comment: Tried your suggestion but seem to get an error, where CUDAMemoryGet[jset] is in red highlight indicating that the function appears in more than one context, with one of the definitions shadowed.  The same error seems to also appear when the initial Needs["CUDALink`] expression is executed, despite giving a ClearAll; command just prior to executing it.  Not sure how to specify the single correct context.

Comment: Have you tried to restart the kernel?

Comment: Yes,  I've turned the machine off multiple times and tried to bang my head against the wall some more to limited effect, except on my head  Cutting and pasting the JuleaCalculate code snippet into a separate file and rerunning (after an operating system upgrade to Windows 11, continues to give me the error "The Kernel is not responding to a Dynamic Evaluation ..."  Internal self-test error: DXScreenGraphics|cpp|174.  Error tells me to "click here" to report but the system hangs and doesn't permit me to do so.  If I then Abort, the Error Message disappears and there is nothing to respond to.

Comment: Upgraded NVidea driver once again and reconfigured GPU developer settings using NVidea control panel.  The system no longer crashes, but all I see is the locator icon moving around by itself on a totally orange screen, with no Julia set visible. If maniulate autorun is set off and then turned on again, the locator locks.

Comment: Try to reevaluate but then all that appears is a grey rectangle as output.

Comment: By invoking command Needs["CUDADRiverLink`] the program now runs without crashing or hanging.  However, there is still no Julia Set displayed as in the example shown online, just an orange panel in manipulate with the circular locator flitting about within it.